# React native router flux and react native camera issue while taking multiple pictures

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux, react-native-camera

I am using react native router flux and react native camera. I recently had this issue.

**Project scenario**

I have a SwipeListView, where swiping right will, give an option to select camera. User select camera ,

```
Actions.showCamera();
```

takes the picture, and the picture is shown in the scene using ImageView. In the ImageView scene, if user likes it, user submits it to server, if user doesnt like it user cancels it and user is back to SwipeListView scene using

```
Actions.showListView();
```

For the first time, when app launches everything works fine, on the second go, when user is back to listview, select camera and take pictures, it renders black screen, no idea whats going on?
Is there anyway that I can debug this? 
Any help/suggestions is highly appreciated.

This is exactly what I am having

https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/issues/565

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and in my case the solution was:

Instead to use the command Actions.showListView(), I used the command Actions.pop() to return to the screen.